Can lead hydroxide react with potassium nitrate?
There's a chemical reaction where $\ce{Pb(NO3)2}$ reacts with $\ce{KOH}$ to form $\ce{KNO3}$ and $\ce{Pb(OH)2}$ (chalky white ppt).
But I have a doubt if the opposite reaction is possible too, i.e. $\ce{Pb(OH)2}$ reacts with $\ce{KNO3}$ to form $\ce{KOH}$ and $\ce{Pb(NO3)2}$. My teacher says neither $\ce{NaNO3}$ nor $\ce{KNO3}$ being solids can react with $\ce{Pb(OH)2}$ to form $\ce{Pb(NO3)2}$, it can only be done by $\ce{HNO3}$ (neutralization Reaction). But, what if I use $\ce{KNO3}$ and $\ce{NaNO3}$ in aqueous state? Will the reaction take place?

Consider  the lead(II) hydroxide solubility product and how hydroxide ions affect it solubility.

No ! In aqueous solution, the reaction between solutions of $\ce{KOH}$ or $\ce{NaOH}$ and $\ce{Pb(NO3)2}$  produce $\ce{Pb(OH)2}$ and some nitrate solution. The reaction cannot be reversed. The equation can be written between molecules or between ions. It gives between dissolved molecules :
$$\ce{Pb(NO3)2 + 2 KOH -> Pb(OH)2 + 2 KNO3}$$
$$\ce{Pb(NO3)2 + 2 NaOH -> Pb(OH)2 + 2 NaNO3}$$
or between ions :
$$\ce{Pb^{2+} + 2 OH- -> Pb(OH)2}$$
In both cases, the insoluble hydroxide $\ce{Pb(OH)2}$ is produced irreversibly. The reaction cannot be reversed.
